# Python given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A in O(n) time complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

For example:

> input: A = [ 6 4 3 -5 0 2 -7 1 ]

> output: 5

Since 5 is the smallest positive integer that does not occur in the array.

---

I have written two solutions to that problem. The first one is good but I don't want to use any external libraries + its O(n)*log(n) complexity. The second solution "In which I need your help to optimize it" gives an error when the input is chaotic sequences length=10005 (with minus).

Solution 1:

```
from itertools import count, filterfalse 


def minpositive(a):
    return(next(filterfalse(set(a).__contains__, count(1))))
```

Solution 2:

```
def minpositive(a):
    count = 0
    b = list(set([i for i in a if i>0]))
    if min(b, default = 0)  > 1 or  min(b, default = 0)  ==  0 :
        min_val = 1
    else:
        min_val = min([b[i-1]+1 for i, x in enumerate(b) if x - b[i - 1] >1], default=b[-1]+1)
        
    return min_val
```

> Note: This was a demo test in codility, solution 1 got 100% and
> solution 2 got 77 %.
> Error in "solution2" was due to:
> Performance tests ->
> medium  chaotic sequences length=10005 (with minus) got 3 expected
> 10000
> Performance tests -> large chaotic + many -1, 1, 2, 3 (with
> minus) got 5 expected 10000

Comment: I think you're assuming `list(set(a))` is sorted but it isn't. It's not clear what you're asking -- are you asking for working code?

Comment: Both are working but I am looking for a way to optimize that code to make work with O(n) time complexity "as stated in my question".

Comment: ThanksPaul for the hint "I think you're assuming list(set(a)) ". It will not impact my second code. I will use sorted in the future.

Comment: This is demo task from https://codility.com :)

Comment: Before adding yet another answer to this question, please remember that if you have to sort, it's already not O(N).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Testing for the presence of a number in a set is fast in Python so you could try something like this:

```
def minpositive(a):
    A = set(a)
    ans = 1
    while ans in A:
       ans += 1
    return ans
```

Comment: Also this takes care of any possible duplicates that could be present in the given list.

Comment: Though a set is generally faster than a list, I disagree converting list to set in this case. Conversion from list still needs iterating over all the N elements. If you don't convert, it takes iterating only an average of N/2 elements to find the number

Answer (score 7):

Fast for large arrays.

```
def minpositive(arr):
    if 1 not in arr: # protection from error if ( max(arr) < 0 )
        return 1
    else:
        maxArr = max(arr) # find max element in 'arr'
        c1 = set(range(2, maxArr+2)) # create array from 2 to max
        c2 = c1 - set(arr) # find all positive elements outside the array
        return min(c2)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have an easy solution. No need to sort.

```
def solution(A):
    s = set(A)
    m = max(A) + 2
    for N in range(1, m):
        if N not in s:
            return N
    return 1
```

Note: It is 100% total score (Correctness & Performance)

Answer (score 3):

```
def minpositive(A):
    """Given an list A of N integers, 
    returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) 
    that does not occur in A in O(n) time complexity

        Args:
            A: list of integers
        Returns:
            integer: smallest positive integer

        e.g:
            A = [1,2,3]
            smallest_positive_int = 4
    """
    len_nrs_list = len(A)
    N = set(range(1, len_nrs_list+2))
    
    return min(N-set(A)) #gets the min value using the N integers
```

Comment: You can get rid of the try/except if you start with `N = set(range(1, len_nrc_list+2))`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution passes the performance test with a score of 100%

```py
def solution(A):
    n = sorted(i for i in set(A) if i > 0)  # Remove duplicates and negative numbers
    if not n:
        return 1
    ln = len(n)

    for i in range(1, ln + 1):
        if i != n[i - 1]:
            return i

    return ln + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(A):
    B = set(sorted(A))
    m = 1
    for x in B:
        if x == m:
            m+=1
    return m
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to explain how your code fixed the problem.

Comment: OP states the time complexity here should be linear time, answer provided here is quadratic time.

Comment: @avizzzy, isn't it `O(n * log n)`? And it could be `O(n)` if the `sorted` call is removed, after all sets are unordered.

Comment: Python sets don't preserve the order in which items were inserted, so this solution should not work. In practice, it seems Python sorts sets of ints up for fairly large max values, but that's probably a consequence of how sets are implemented, it is now a feature you can count on.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on from Niroj Shrestha and najeeb-jebreel, added an initial portion to avoid iteration in case of a complete set. Especially important if the array is very large.

```
def smallest_positive_int(A):
  sorted_A = sorted(A)
  last_in_sorted_A = sorted_A[-1]
  #check if straight continuous list
  if len(sorted_A) == last_in_sorted_A:
    return last_in_sorted_A + 1
  else:
    #incomplete list, iterate to find the smallest missing number
    sol=1
    for x in sorted_A:
        if x == sol:
          sol += 1
        else:
          break
    return sol

A = [1,2,7,4,5,6]
print(smallest_positive_int(A))
```

Comment: This solution does not work if there are duplicates in A.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't *really* need another answer, but there is a solution that has not been proposed yet, that I believe to be faster than what's been presented so far.

As others have pointed out, we know the answer lies in the range `[1, len(A)+1]`, inclusively. We can turn that into a set and take the minimum element in the set difference with A. That's a good O(N) solution since set operations are O(1).

However, we don't need to use a Python set to store `[1, len(A)+1]`, because we're starting with a dense set. We can use an array instead, which will replace set hashing by list indexing and give us another O(N) solution with a lower constant.

```
def minpositive(a):
    # the "set" of possible answer - values_found[i-1] will tell us whether i is in a
    values_found = [False] * (len(a)+1)
    # note any values in a in the range [1, len(a)+1] as found
    for i in a:
        if i > 0 and i <= len(a)+1:
            values_found[i-1] = True
    # extract the smallest value not found
    for i, found in enumerate(values_found):
        if not found:
            return i+1
```

We know the final for loop always finds a value that was not marked, because it has one more element than `a`, so at least one of its cells was not set to `True`.

Comment: Not sure if it was intended with this solution, but if you have an integer list like e.g: a = [2,3,2], it returns 2 values -> 1, 4

Comment: @mseromenho I'm not sure what you mean. I just tested `print(minpositive([2,3,2]))` and it gave me `1`.

Comment: my bad, I was testing the code wrongly, I was printing directly from the for loop! Good solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_min(a):
    x= max(a)
    if x-1 in a:
        return x+1
    elif x <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x-1
```

Correct me if i'm wrong but this works for me.

Comment: I really don't understand how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(A):
clone = 1
A.sort()
for itr in range(max(A) + 2):
    if itr not in A and itr >= 1:
        clone = itr
        break
return clone

print(solution([2,1,4,7]))

#returns 3
```

Comment: This is a quadratic time solution: `itr not in A` takes linear time, and you might run it a linear number of times. It may look simple, but it really does not answer the question, which is to solve this problem is O(n) time complexity.

Comment: If you have to sort, it's already > O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(A):
    n = 1
    for i in A:
        if n in A:
            n = n+1 
        else:
            return n
    return n
```

Comment: While `for i in A` should work as expected, it semes redundant to define both `i` and `n`. More importantly, this is O(n^2) performance. `if n in A` is O(n), and you are doing this up to n times.

Answer (score 0):

```
def not_in_A(a):
    a=sorted(a)
    if max(a)<1:
        return(1)
    for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
        if a[i+1]-a[i]>1:
            out=a[i]+1
            if out==0 or out<1:
                continue
            return(out)
            
    return(max(a)+1)
```

Comment: `sorted` is automatically not O(N)...

Answer (score 0):

mark and then find the first one that didn't find

```py
nums = [ 6, 4, 3, -5, 0, 2, -7, 1 ]
def check_min(nums):
    marks = [-1] * len(nums)
    for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num >= 0:
            marks[num] = idx
    for idx, mark in enumerate(marks):
        if mark == -1:
            return idx
    return idx + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I just modified the answer by @najeeb-jebreel and now the function gives an optimal solution.

```
def solution(A):
    sorted_set = set(sorted(A))
    sol = 1
    for x in sorted_set:
        if x == sol:
            sol += 1
        else:
            break
    return sol
```

Answer (score -1):

I reduced the length of set before comparing

```
a=[1,222,3,4,24,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,2,3,3,11,-1]
#a=[1,2,3,6,3]
def sol(a_array):
    a_set=set()
    b_set=set()
    cnt=1
    for i in a_array:

        #In order to get the greater performance
        #Checking if element is greater than length+1 
        #then it can't be output( our result in solution)
        
        if i<=len(a) and i >=1:
            
            a_set.add(i) # Adding array element in set 
            b_set.add(cnt) # Adding iterator in set
            cnt=cnt+1
    b_set=b_set.difference(a_set)
    if((len(b_set)) > 1): 
        return(min(b_set))
    else:
        return max(a_set)+1

sol(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def solution(A):
    nw_A = sorted(set(A))
    if all(i < 0 for i in nw_A):
        return 1
    else:
        ans = 1
        while ans in nw_A:
            ans += 1
            if ans not in nw_A:
                return ans
```

For better performance if there is a possibility to import numpy package.

```py
def solution(A):
    import numpy as np
    nw_A = np.unique(np.array(A))
    if np.all((nw_A < 0)):
        return 1
    else:
        ans = 1
        while ans in nw_A:
            ans += 1
            if ans not in nw_A:
                return ans
```

Comment: You're sorting the array up to N times, so your time complexity is O(n^2 * log n), a long way off the mark!

Answer (score -1):

```
def solution(A):
# write your code in Python 3.6
min_num = float("inf")
set_A = set(A)
# finding the smallest number
for num in set_A:
    if num < min_num:
        min_num = num
# print(min_num)

#if negative make positive 
if min_num < 0 or min_num == 0:
    min_num = 1
# print(min_num)

# if in set add 1 until not 
while min_num in set_A:  
    min_num += 1
return min_num
```

Not sure why this is not 100% in correctness. It is 100% performance

Answer (score -2):

```
def solution(A):
    arr = set(A)
    N = set(range(1, 100001))
    while N in arr:
       N += 1
    return min(N - arr)

solution([1, 2, 6, 4])
#returns 3
```